# Powershell Where-Object in (Array)

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm grabbing an array (I think?) of certificate thumbprints that are going to expire in 10 days

```
$DaysToExpiration = 10
$expirationDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysToExpiration)

$ExpiringCerts = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\webhosting | where-object {$_.notafter -le $expirationDate}

$ExpiringCerts | Format-table -Autosize Thumbprint, FriendlyName, NotAfter
```

That returns what I want.
I'm under the impression that $ExpiringCerts is now an array of values?
Now I want to get a list of IIS Site bindings where the Thumbprint is IN the list $ExpiringCerts.Thumbprint

```
$certs = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | Where-object {$_.Thumbprint -in $ExpiringCerts.Thumbprint} | Sort-Object -Property $_.Sites.Value | Foreach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Site = $_.Sites.Value
        Thumbprint = $_.Thumbprint
        IPAddress = $_.IPAddress
    } 
}

$Certs
```

This does not work. I get nothing. If I remove the Where-Object part, I get the full list of IIS sites and Thumbprints. I can say something like

```
Where-object {$_.Thumbprint -eq "D18A3112G2D3B1975401FC75C459081448F7A428"}
```

That works fine and returns what I'd expect.

How can I return only results where the thumbprint is in another list defined by a variable?

Comment: As currently written, `$ExpiringCerts` could be `$null` or an object of `X509Certificate2` type, or an array of the latter. Try `$ExpiringCerts = @(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\webhosting | where-object {$_.notafter -le $expirationDate})` - it's always an array however you need  to use `| Where-object {($ExpiringCerts.Count -gt 0) -and ($_.Thumbprint -in $ExpiringCerts.Thumbprint)}` later…